# CSS3 - Style a span like an Square-Arrow

Tags: html, css

i was tired to style a simple span with different texts inside (Text, Big Text, ..) to an Square-Arrow (see Picutre).

[image: Square-Arrow]

I have tried this by using a simple background, an Border an an Border-Image. But no solution has worked as propper. By using a background you will get problems if the text becomes larger, because of the strech. By using an Border you cant get that arrow/triangle on the right side. An the Border-Image gave me an creepy result...

The biggest problem on my side is the dynamic text. I have to set different texts with different length to the span. So if i have an bigger Text the the it should not strech the hole background, because thats looks very creepy.

[image: Big Text]

Are there some tricks or do you have some tipps to get an good solution?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Tip: use `:before` and `:after` to create two simple arrows on the right side: one black, and one slightly smaller white.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/#article-header-id-2

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single `::after` pseudo-element to create this effect.

The clever part is using `transform: rotate(45deg);` to turn the pseudo-element 45 degrees, which creates the square arrow.

```css
.arrow {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 0 36px 36px 0;
padding: 6px 0 6px 6px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 18px;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
border: 2px solid rgb(0,0,0);
border-right: none;
border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.arrow::after {
content:'';
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: 3px;
right: -12px;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
border-top: 2px solid rgb(0,0,0);
border-right: 2px solid rgb(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 4px 0 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="arrow">Text</span>
<span class="arrow">Big Text</span>
<span class="arrow">Very Big Text</span>
<span class="arrow">Quite Spectacularly Big Text</span>
<span class="arrow">Phenomenally, Astoundingly, Almost Preposterously Big Text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:before` and `:after` to draw a triangle. One will be black, and the second white on top of it, a bit smaller.

Here is a Snippet

```css
body{
padding:30px;  
}
span {
  font:20px/20px arial,sans-serif;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
  position:relative;
}
span:after {
content: "";
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 22.5px 0px 22.5px 34px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: -34px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
span:before {
content: "";
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 23.5px 0px 23.5px 35px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
right: -35px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Hello, this is my text</span></div>
```

That was just a test, I did'nt check in every browser for compatibility, but it's a way to do it.

If the height is always the same, you can also use an image and make it appear thanks to an `:after`